# Twilio installation problem

Tags: software-compilation, software-compatibility

During the installation of Twilio, using the command `sudo pip install twilio`, I get the following error:

```
compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4pUp83/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-70PoKH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4pUp83/cryptography/
```

Has anybody experienced the same problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: This appears to be extremely similar to the issue described [here](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-energenie/issues/11). Could you walk through some of the recommendations there (particularly [aQuaYi's comment](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-energenie/issues/11#issuecomment-225473219)) and report back?

Answer (score 0):

On a different SBC I ran into this issue, the link mentioned in comment didn't work for me ('sudo aprt-get install python-dev')

Instead the following did.

```
sudo apt-get install python python-pip python-setuptools python-dev build-essential -y

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

You might be able to get away with just the 3rd command but my log of commands for debugging required running all three. ie: Installing twilio/ngrok server on OPi Zero v1.4